# custom resourses in EAR

Tags: java, maven, resources, ear

i'm creating some EAR application on `WildFly` using MAVEN
i need to place some config files,logs,and user scripts in EAR so ,that those files can be read or write by user by simple editor and i can read\write to those files from any classes in any dependent ejb or war module.
i can place those files on `\src\main\application\somedir`  directory in ear module, 
but i can NOT access to those files by `getResourceAsStream()` from dependent modules
can you point me to some solution? 
i must to specify question. the question is NOT "where i must place files to load them from particular class"
the question IS "what i must do, if i need files to read\write from some module of EAR AND user can edit them by simple editor  "

Comment: getResourceAsStream() will look for files in your CLASSPATH however its READ-ONLY file. If you want to write to these files then you need to put it on the filesystem(FS) and reference them by the FS fullpath.

Answer (score 0):

*getResourceAsStream()* search for file in classpath. The EAR file content is not on your classpath.

Solution: put the file to a war (inside your EAR) then you can read it with the following java code:

```
*.war\WEB-INF\classes\config.properties

getResourceAsStream("config.properties")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you place it in your classes/package/resources (or in WEB-INF/classes) you can get an InputStream to it using the class loader, U can use some generic like this:

```
InputStream isFile = SomeClassInTheSamePackage.class.getResourceAsStream("yourFileName");
```

OR if u are using apache/tomcat u can use some thing like this:

```
String catPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");//"user.dir"
String path = catPath + "webapps" + File.separator + "nameOfYourApp.ear/.war/.jar";
File myFile = new File(path);
BufferedOutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(myFile));
//buffer.
buffer.close();
```

I hope that's help you.